# django-cms menu not showing

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to run a project in which header has some menu links which are not loaded. The code to load the menu is as follows

```
<ul>
{% load menu_tags %}

{% for child in children %}
  <li><a {% if forloop.first %} class="first" {% endif %}href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It looks that the for loop is not running as the children array is empty. I am not getting the idea where to look for this children array. From where this array gets loaded. If django-cms query the database then what columns does it query.

The project was actually built on some older version of django 2.1. Now I am trying to run the project on django-cms 3.0.7. I am using mysql database and have imported the data.

Answer (score 3):

As well as importing the data, you need to do some additional work.

See:

- http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/upgrade/2.1.html
- http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/upgrade/2.4.html
- http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/upgrade/3.0.html

There are some steps there that you can't leave out. In particular, see the notes in that second document about migrations, and about the `cms moderator` command.

Don't do *anything* without first making a database backup.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those links I have gone through those steps. What I found is I am not importing the database properly. Is there some proper way of importing data dump of django-cms from previous version to new version i.e get data dump from django-cms version 2.1 to 3.0.7. django-cms schema has changed and migration is not working perfectly in my case

Comment: Are you trying to do this in one go? I would take it step-by-step - from 2.1 to 2.3, to 2.4, to 3.0.